# Is the integral of $x^n$ unbounded for $n<0$, over the finite interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I have solved the question above and found that the Option C is correct. But I am unable to understand 2nd option. Can you help me with it?

My Attempt at solving the question:-

$$ I_n= \int_0^1 x^n dx  $$
$$ I_n = \frac{1^{n+1} - 0^{n+1}}{n+1} $$
Option A: For $n = -1$ the integral does not exists.

Option C: For $n = 1,2,3... m$, the integral becomes  $ \frac{1}{n+1}$ and consequently the product $I_1  I_2.... I_m$ becomes $\frac{1}{(m+1)!}$

Option D: We can see from above that $I_m ...... <I_3< I_2 < I_1$

Can you please help for Option B?
Thank you!

Comment: actually $I_m < \dots < I_3<I_2< I_1$

Comment: @FormulaWriter Yeah Yeah! My bad, I wrote that in a hurry!

Comment: But what about B?

Comment: Depends on the author what "finite" refers to. It could be that "The term finite .. is stressing the fact that it is 'defined', 'well defined' or 'exists as a real number'". Or, "finite on a set sometimes meant bounded on the set.". See [What does “finite but unbounded” mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961407/what-does-finite-but-unbounded-mean).

Comment: @Its_me okay so i just saw that and thought about it and i believe the option B  it to be correct since for n<0, the integrals are going to ln(x) , -1/x, -1/2x^2 and so on... and all these are not bounded but are finite in the interval (0,1). So am I right in my reasoning?

Comment: Have you noticed that B talks about the integrands and not the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Its_me is correct: The B question talks about the *integrand*, not the *integral*. The integrand is the function that is being integrated, in this case, $f(x) = x^n$ with $n < 0$. By unbounded, it means

- For every $M > 0$, there is some $x \in (0,1)$ such that $|f(x)| > M$.

By finite, they just mean

- For every $x \in (0,1), |f(x)| < \infty$, or more appropriately, that $f(x)$ is defined for every $x \in (0,1)$.

I trust you can show both, though if you haven't encountered a full definition of $x^n$ for irrational $n$ yet, you may have to skip those details you've never been taught.